# How to create a custom step slider/range group?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, slider

I know how to set a background for a radio group and custom image for radio button. My question is, how would I create a range slider like this one used in the Uber app that changes the image of the radio button for each position as well as invokes a specified function/action when in that position automatically? For example, if the user stops on the second position, which would be sort by a>z, it would automatically sort the list a>z.

[image: custom slider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radio group returns a result when the user selects an option right? a number or a user defined value?

Use an `OnClickListener` or `OnChangeListener` to analyse the result, then run it through a switch statement that performs the relevant task.

Comment: I'll try that but what about changing the image based on position programmatically?

Comment: You could set the value that the radio group returns to the name of the image required, then parse that into the URI for the image needed.

Comment: So for example  say the URI  is something like ".../images/radioImages/imageTEMP.png" then replace TEMP with the value returned from the radio group and set that as the image icon. Or in the case of Android might be Res.drawable.radioimageTEMP.png or something right?

Comment: HI @SteveC.can you accept this answer if it helped you?

Comment: How is this implemented with a `RadioGroup`?  I thought the underlying implementation is a `SeekBar`.